# I get an error while trying to run this Unity-C# Script (Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration)

Tags: c#

```cs
public class SampleCustomHeader : MonoBehaviour
{
    const float BUTTON_HEIGHT = 50.0f;
    const string CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY_NAME = "custom_timestamp";

    WebViewObject_webviewObject

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        float h = Screen.height;
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(.0f, h - BUTTON_HEIGHT, Screen.width, BUTTON_HEIGHT), "check for request header"))
        {
            this._webviewObject = GameObject.Find("WebViewObject").GetComponent<WebViewObject>();
            this._webviewObject.LoadURL("http://httpbin.org/headers");
        }
        h -= BUTTON_HEIGHT;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(.0f, h - BUTTON_HEIGHT, Screen.width, BUTTON_HEIGHT), "add custom header"))
        {
            this._webviewObject = GameObject.Find("WebViewObject").GetComponent<WebViewObject>();
            this._webviewObject.AddCustomHeader(CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY_NAME, System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        h -= BUTTON_HEIGHT;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(.0f, h - BUTTON_HEIGHT, Screen.width, BUTTON_HEIGHT), "get custom header"))
        {
            this._webviewObject = GameObject.Find("WebViewObject").GetComponent<WebViewObject>();
            Debug.Log("custom_timestamp is " + this._webviewObject.GetCustomHeaderValue(CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY_NAME));
        }
        h -= BUTTON_HEIGHT;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(.0f, h - BUTTON_HEIGHT, Screen.width, BUTTON_HEIGHT), "remove custom header"))
        {
            this._webviewObject = GameObject.Find("WebViewObject").GetComponent<WebViewObject>();
            this._webviewObject.RemoveCustomHeader(CUSTOM_HEADER_KEY_NAME);
        }
        h -= BUTTON_HEIGHT;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(.0f, h - BUTTON_HEIGHT, Screen.width, BUTTON_HEIGHT), "clear custom header"))
        {
            this._webviewObject = GameObject.Find("WebViewObject").GetComponent<WebViewObject>();
            this._webviewObject.ClearCustomHeader();
        }
        h -= BUTTON_HEIGHT;
    }
}
```

What is wrong there? I didn't write the code tho but I really need it. I'm running Unity 2020.3.5f1 Personal . I use Notepad++ for the C# Editor. If I remove it then there are more errors.

Error is at (18,5): error CS1519: Invalid token 'void' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: What is the WebViewObject thing supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

Line 6:

```
 WebViewObject_webviewObject
```

I'm going to assume you (or someone else) forgot to put a space before `_` and a semicolon (`;`) at the end.